# Looking for a way to hold a reference to a class so that I can dynamically instantiate it later

Tags: crystal-lang

I've created [this playground](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4593) which should make my question more clear but in a nutshell, I'm looking for a way to pass a reference to a class name to another class's initializer so that at a later stage in the compilation process I can instantiate that class and do something with it.

```
class Route
  property action : Class

  def initialize(@action)
  end

  def do_something
    @action.new.call
  end
end

class Action
  def call
    puts "called"
  end
end

route = Route.new(Action)
```

however, the above gives me
    `can't use Object as the type of an instance variable yet, use a more specific type`

I understand this is something that might not yet be implemented in the language but I was wondering if there was another way to achieve this seeing as I can't really do as the error suggested and be more specific because I need to accept any class.

Hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try generics:

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 233 bytes

```ruby
class Route(T)
  property action : T

  def initialize(@action)
  end

  def do_something
    @action.new.call
  end
end

class Action
  def call
    puts "called"
  end
end

route = Route(Action.class).new(Action)
route.do_something
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5LCsMwDAX3OYXIKtn4AIVCe4WSfTG22gpcO9gKJb28648KWeppRnom7om1y9k4nRLcwsY4LfMAsMawYuQdtGEKHk6wDCW2@ADyxKQdfXG69G0V0Ns/YMM9hTfyi/yzRACCKY8fZbRzgjelf742QHxBSomNE4x1RDsepViLwlkKd1m1S3N9IsncOXXsk/MP)

Comment: Even shorter :p https://carc.in/#/r/45f2 (no need to specify the generic)